# How can I include repeated measures to my lmer correctly

Tags: r, lme4, random-effects

In my study I was sampling the same sites in different regions for many years. Each site has different properties in each year, which is important for my research question. I want to know, if the properties of the site affect biodiversity on the sites. And I am interested in the interaction of the propterties and the regions.

Overview:

- Biodiversity = response
- Site property = fixed factor, changes every year
- Region = fixed factor , same regions every year
- Site = random effect, is repeatedly sampled in the different sampling years
- Year = random effect, is the factor in which "site" is repeated

At the moment my model looks like this:

```
mod1 <- lmer(biodiversity~region*siteProperty+(1|Year)+(1|site))
```

I'm not sure if this accounts for the repeated measures.
Alternatively I was thinking about this one, as it includes also the nestedness of the sites in the years, but maybe that is not necessary:

```
mod2 <- lmer(biodiversity~region*siteProperty+(1|Year)+(1|Year:site))
```

The problem with this approach is, that it only works if my site properties are not zero. But I have zeros in different properties and I need to analyse their effects as well.

If you need more information, just ask me for.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your first example,

```
mod1 <- lmer(biodiversity~region*siteProperty+(1|Year)+(1|site))
```

should be fine (although I'd encourage you to use the `data` argument explicitly ...).  If you have samples for "many years" for each site, you might want to consider

- including a trend model (i.e. include `Year`, as a numeric variable, in the fixed effects part of the model as well, either as a simple linear term or as part of an additive model, e.g. using `splines::ns`
- checking for/allowing for autocorrelation (although this is tricky in `lme4`; you can use `lme`, but then crossed random effects of `Year` and `site` become harder).

If you have one sample per site/year combination, you *don't* want `(1|Site:year)`, because that will be the same as the residual variability term.

Your statement "only works if my site properties are not zero" doesn't make sense to me: in general, having zeros in predictor variables shouldn't cause any problems ... ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure if this second model not works, because of the zeros. It was just the only difference I could find. I'll try to consider year as a factor and see what happens.